# What's the etiquette for moving a question?

Tags: support, etiquette

I've asked a question on ServerFault but I (now) suspect DBA may be a better fit. It's shades of gray as usual but now I'm curious.

Should I just repost there and let the question get closed here? Is there a way to "export" a question?

Comment: I believe [this is the question in question](http://serverfault.com/questions/472119/mongodb-replicaset-failover-incurs-1000x-query-response-time-increase)?

Comment: A lot of it is covered by this blog post. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/

Answer (score 3):

Extraordinarily good questions can be migrated to other Stack Exchange sites - Flag your question for moderator attention if you think it is such an extraordinary question, tell us where you think it belongs, and the moderators will look at it and decide if it's something we're comfortable pitching over the wall.
The worst we'll do is decline your request to migrate the question (and we'll usually tell you why).

You can also ask (politely) in [the other site's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) to see if they (a) want the question, or (b) want to come over here and help us answer it.

If you think we've got our heads up our butts for declining your migration (or don't want to wait for us) and the users on the other site think it's a good fit you can also delete your question here and re-ask it on the other site.

---

In the case of [your MongoDB question](https://serverfault.com/questions/472119/mongodb-replicaset-failover-incurs-1000x-query-response-time-increase) I'm not certain DBA is the right place for it -- It may be a Mongo problem, or it may be a PHP glitch.
I'd like to see you do a little more legwork (try using the Mongo command line tools to connect, check the logs from your PHP application and any load-balancing components, make sure virtual IPs are moving over like they should, etc.) before punting this to the DBA folks.

Comment: Thanks voretaq7... re: the actual question on ServerFault (not this discussion), definitely done my homework. I dislike questions that have so much information attached that the casual browser flees in terror. I tried to be judicious with the info but I've cut out the load balancers, removed auth, played with mongo's command line/verbose logging/profiling, experimented with the mongo-php driver settings, etc. etc. Happy to leave the question here. If you think it's appropriate for ServerFault vs DBA then good enough for me.

Comment: @John it could go either way, so if you don't get an answer here after a few days you might want to check with the DBA folks (but if you tell us more about what you've eliminated it would help on either site - trimming information is good, but if we know what you've eliminated we don't have to think about it too much :)

Comment: `Extraordinarily good questions can be migrated[...]`: I stopped reading here as I needed to recover from an outburst of laughter.